# Exim - block incoming mail from blacklisted IPS only

Tags: exim, spamassassin, blacklist, rbl

I would like to check for blacklists only for incoming e-mail. I have users who usually get dynamic IP's which are blacklisted so they are not able to send the e-mail if I turn the blacklist option on.
How could I achieve that ?
Also, is there a ways to set automatic deletion of e-mails marked as SPAM ?

Here is my exim cofnfiguration. 
http://paste.servergur.us/wilumojabi.coffee

Answer (score 0):

You have to *whitelist* legal senders while all others are passed through the blacklist. But far more efficient way is to use SMTPS with authentication.

`exim` intended to ask `spamd` about score from the ACL, and if score is high enough - simply reject or blackhole the message. Delivering + deletion is a wasting of resources.

Answer (score 0):

Think about it from the opposite direction: You want to limit RBL checks to only those inbound emails which are not coming from authenticated users:

```
deny message       = rejected because $sender_host_address is in a black list \
                     at $dnslist_domain\\n$dnslist_text
    !authenticated = *
     dnslists      = ${readfile {/etc/exim/dnsbl.conf}{:}}
```

Your second question can be addressed in two ways.  One option is that you can deliver spam directly to the user's Spam folder instead of their Inbox.

```
# Add X-Spam-Flag if spam is over system-wide threshold for non-authed users
warn   condition      = ${if >{$message_size}{500K}{no}{yes}}
       !authenticated = *
       spam           = exim
       add_header     = X-Spam-Flag: Yes
       set acl_m_filter_to_spam = 1

# In transport which actually delivers the email, if $acl_m_filter_to_spam
# is set, I append ".Spam/" to the maildir delivery path
```

The other option is that you reject the message instead of accepting it.

```
# Reject spams with score over limit for non-authed users
deny   condition      = ${if >{$message_size}{500K}{no}{yes}}
       !authenticated = *
       message        = This message scored $spam_score points.  Rejected.
       spam           = exim:true
       condition      = ${if >{${eval10:$spam_score_int/10}}{INBOUND_SPAM_LIMIT}}
```

In my case, I actually do both of these.  I mark an email as spam if it scores a 5.0 or higher.  I filter it to the Spam folder if it scores a 5.0 to a 5.9.  I reject the email completely if it scores a 6.0 or higher.

Note that the above Spam examples are for regular inbound email.  I have that entire section duplicated to scan SMTP Authenticated users that send mail too, I just have different scores enabled/disabled and have set different spam and rejection thresholds.